# ForAll Loop breaks inline images of email in Lotus Notes

Tags: email, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, email-attachments, lotusscript

I do have a Lotus Notes email containing inline images. When I run the following lines of code which simply changes the subject of the email the inline images is lost.

```
Sub Initialize

Dim ns As New NotesSession
Dim nc As NotesDocumentCollection
Dim nd As NotesDocument

Set nc = ns.Currentdatabase.Unprocesseddocuments()  
Set nd = nc.GetFirstDocument()

    ForAll Items In nd.Items

    End ForAll

Call nd.Replaceitemvalue("Subject", "Forall")
Call nd.Save(True, False)

End Sub
```

The problem is caused by the ForAll loop which actually doesn't do anything. If the loop is commented out the inline images still remain on the email.

[image: original email with inline image]

[image: email after forall loop]

I'm hoping any of you guys has an idea or advise how to solve this issue.

Cheers,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

Your message body is probably being converted from Notes rich text to MIME when the item is accessed and then being re-saved, with a loss of fidelity.

Try setting `ns.ConvertMIME = false` at the beginning of your code.